# Need help with $\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\ \text{Li}_{\sqrt{2}}(-x)\ dx$

Tags: special-functions, improper-integrals, closed-form

I need help with solving this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\ \text{Li}_{\sqrt{2}}(-x)\ dx,$$
where $\text{Li}_{s}(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\ \text{Li}_{\sqrt{2}}(-x)\ \mathrm dx=-2^{\sqrt{2}}\pi.$$

---

*Proof:*

Use formula (3) from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) to get an integral representation of the polylogarithm:
$$\text{Li}_s(-x)=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{k^{s-1}}{\frac{e^k}{x}-1}\mathrm dk.$$
Then, changing the order of integration,
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-p}\ \text{Li}_s(-x)\mathrm dx=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-p}\,\ k^{s-1}}{\frac{e^k}{x}-1}\mathrm dx\ \mathrm dk=\\\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(s)\sin \pi p}\int_0^\infty e^{k(1-p)}\ k^{s-1}\mathrm dk=\frac{\pi}{(p-1)^s \sin \pi p}$$